# Sharing an SSIS Package between multiple projects

Tags: sql, generics, ssis, sql-server-2012

I've run into a scenario at a client where we have a single generic ssis package that needs to be used by multiple SSIS projects. Normally, we would copy the SSIS package in question and add it to each of the projects that need it. The trouble is that as this generic packages gets developed, the changes need to be added to all of the SSIS projects that use this generic package.

The ideal situation would be to put the package in a DLL and load that DLL to all of the projects so that we could just update the DLL version in the SSIS projects, but I haven't found a way for SSIS to interface with a DLL.

An alternative would be to combine all of these projects into a single folder with different dtproj files for each project, but this is not an ideal solution since we will have multiple developers making changes on these packages and it will increase the number of merge conflicts between otherwise unrelated projects.

Anyone have a suggestion here?

Comment: A google search on `ssis reusable components` might reveal something useful.  This, for example, https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2841/creating-ssis-package-templates-for-reusability/

Comment: @DanBracuk That's a pretty cool technique that I can definitely utilize for template packages, but I'm not sure it applies to my situation. I need to be able to push updates to multiple projects at once. this post on [creating custom tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692779/ssis-how-do-you-reuse-script-in-a-scripting-component-in-another-package) is closer to what I need, but I would love it if there was a way for a dev to open the project and see that there are pending updates for the common package

Comment: Also, I think utilizing templates is a great long term solution once development stabilizes on this common package, which may be the answer to my question

Comment: Currently exploring creating a project for common packages that my other deployed projects can reference: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39039417/ssis-master-package-executing-packages-from-another-project)

Comment: I'm thinking maybe put the generic package in its own project and use the legacy deployment model to deploy it to the file system.  Projects that want to use it would have to reference it as an External Reference instead of Project, but otherwise it might work.

Comment: @TabAlleman yeah, thats the direction I'm currently trying out

Comment: ok, tried the direction where I am executing a package from another project using SQL: `EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] ...` but that would require every account in my projects to have admin rights to SSISDB, which is a big no-no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up going the route where I would either deploy a project as packages and external reference these packages in my project, or to keep the common project and run the packages using a sql script. Details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38346984/ssis-execute-package-task-on-sql-server-2016) for anyone else interested.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use an EXE instead of a DLL? You could then use an Execute Process Task.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. If the External Reference doesn't work then this is definitely a Plan B